# Error de conexion a SQL SERVER Mediante ip publica

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo instalado `xammp` en mi computadora de casa, estoy desarrollando un inventario web para una empresa, ya esta listo, establecí una conexión local desde la empresa al servidor de la misma y sin problemas se conecto, después quise probar la conexión desde fuera de la empresa a través de su `ip` publica y funciono de igual forma, el problema es que llegue este lunes a implementar nuevas características a la pagina, pero al momento de hacer conexión al servidor con la `ip` publica me sale este error:

> [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 1326 [code] =>
>   1326 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Proveedor de
>   canalizaciones con nombre: No se pudo abrir una conexi�n con SQL
>   Server [1326] Ha finalizado el tiempo de espera de inicio de sesi�n
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Error relacionado con la red
>   o espec�fico de instancia al establecer conexi�n con el servidor SQL
>   Server. El servidor no se encuentra o no est� accesible. Compruebe si
>   el nombre de la instancia es correcto y si SQL Server est� configurado
>   para permitir conexiones remotas.

Este es mi código:

```
$serverName = "206.18.78.5";//NOMBRE DEL SERVIDOR    
$connectionInfo = array("DATABASE"=>"ESTRELLA", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"hjhff254");

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);//SE EJECUTA LA CONEXION
    if( $conn ) {
    }else{
         echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br/>";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

Comment: La conexión a la ip publica la hiciste por fqdn (algun.dominio.com) o por ip? Si es por ip, estás seguro que es ip estática? Y también fijates si la instancia de sqlserver está levantada y/o los servicios que necesites (Browser si fuera el caso)

Comment: por ip, y si es una ip estatica, ya habia hecho conexion incluso el domingo pasado accedi a la base de datos desde mi casa y funciono sin problemas, con ip local si funciona pero con la ip publica no.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que hayan hecho alguna modificación en el firewall y ahora se bloqueen los accesos al puerto 1433?

Comment: ese es el problema ayer justamente estuve con el administrador de redes de la empresa y revisamos si los puertos se habian modificado, pero no todo esta bien configurado, tambien pregunte si por error no habian cambiado la ip de estaica a dinamica, pero revisamos y sigue en su lugar todo.

Comment: debo mencionar que ese servidor cuenta con windows server 2008 y tienen alojadas dos paginas web en el mismo y al momento de acceder a esas paginas utilizan la misma ip que yo declaro en mi codigo php y esas paginas si acceden al servidor pero la mia no.

Comment: Te fijaste los servicios que estén levantados, dependiendo como accedes podes estar necesitando el servicio Browser de SQLServer?

Comment: si, estan levantados, pero no revisamos a fondo las conexiones remotas desde sql server, dejenme revisar con el administrador